# Disable autocorrect from specific application

Tags: auto-correct

I'm using my device to do code with Jside and I absolutely need to disable autocorrection. Is there a way to specify application that shall not use autocorrection ?

(Since I'm using swiftkey a lot I need it for texting etc..)

Comment: You could probably do this with root and Tasker (detect which app has come into the foreground and turn auto-correct on/off accordingly), but no there is no built-in way to do this.

Comment: @MatthewRead This is perfect exactly what I needed Thank you ! If you post you answer bellow I will gladly accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this, but you could probably do it with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and root.  You can create a trigger on application foreground/background to turn auto-correct on or off depending on which app it was.  I am not sure of the specifics since I haven't used Tasker but hopefully you can figure it out.  [This Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/1yw1qe/is_it_possible_for_tasker_to_automatically_change/cfo9193) is for a similar task (switching keyboards) and might be a good place to start.

[AutomateIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage) might be able to do this as well.